# Corona SDK: Saving Scores

Tags: json, lua, coronasdk

I am making a game in Corona SDK in which I want to be able to save the player's high score to the device that they are using's disk, just so that it will stay saved even if the user restarts the app.

Problem is, everywhere I go online for help on this sort of thing I am told I should be using JSON, but I am not sure if there is a simpler way of doing things or even if JSON is the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try [Introducing new preference storage features](https://coronalabs.com/blog/2016/09/21/introducing-new-preference-storage-features/).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I tried doing what you recommended, but it didn't work. I basically did exactly what was on the bottom of here: https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/system/getPreference.html

Note, I am using integers to keep track of my score, nothing too complex.

Answer (score 0):

heres a neat thought that may work. make a new scene that contains the high score variable but dont erase the variable when exiting. then everytime they want to check their high score they just have to go to the scene.

option 2 - this one is a bit more tricky and im not exactly sure if you need permissions aka administrator rights (and if you are submitting your app on googleplay you may need to ask for permission. so review the rules before doing it), write a batch file that copies the highscore into a new file.

option 1 is better because you are not necessarily adding anything.